# Register not working (Unsuccessful)

Tags: php, html

first of all, I tried many ways to registered and it just don't work. So, I have made a simple form something like this

```
<form id="myForm" action="actions/register.php" method="POST">  
                <p> Email Address : </p>
                <p> <input name="email" required="required" type="text" placeholder="eg. john.wick@yahoo.com"/> </p>

                <p> Password : </p>
                <p> <input name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Your password"/> </p>

                <p> Confirmation Password : </p>
                <p> <input name="#" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Confirmation password"/> </p>
        <p class="centre"> <input type="submit" value="REGISTER"> </p>
    </form>
```

Therefore, this action will connect to `register.php`. Something like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php error_reporting(-1); ?>
<?php 

    include "../config/dbconnect.php";


        $emailAddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $registerPassword = $_POST['password'];

        $emailAddress = $mysqli->real_escape_string($emailAddress);
        $registerPassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string($registerPassword);

        $salt = sha1(md5($registerPassword));
        $hashedPW = md5($registerPassword.$salt);

        $check = "SELECT * FROM memberTable where email = '$emailAddress'";
        $checkTitle = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($checkTitle) > 0) {
       header("location: ../index.php");
    } else {
        $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO memberTable (email, password, name) VALUES ('$emailAddress', '$hashedPW', '$name')";
        $queryResult = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        if($queryResult) {
            $user_info = array(
                'name' => $name,
            );

        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info;
        }

        header("location: ../index.php");
        exit;
    }

        mysqli_close($mysqli);
    ?>
```

Furthermore, this register.php has connection with dbconnect.php. Something like this:

```
  <?php
    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','database_name');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

The problem when I registered, it went directly to register.php and stopped there. Just a blank space. I have put `error_reporting(-1);`, but it still doesn't want to show any errors at all. Any ideas? How do I show all errors so that I can see what problems I am having. Cheers!

Comment: try to put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` above `error_reporting(-1)`. Maybe php is reporting, but not displaying errors.

Comment: `"It will be better if you can solve all problems including succesful register into my database"` -> You're a funny guy ;)

Comment: Black pages means you have syntax error.
try changing error reporting value to 1:
    `error_reporting(1);`

Comment: Please have a look at [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create secure passwords instead of using sha1+md5+salts

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for the information, I will have a look into it.

Comment: @bcesars passing `1` as a parameter is equivalent to the `E_ERROR` constant. But with the value `-1` _all_ errors of _any_ type will be shown. With `E_ERROR` you're omitting some quite important error messages (important for dev/debug that is), such as `E_PARSE`. Please read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for further info. (Note: passing `E_ALL` might be better, as it's more clear what is intended)

Comment: @giorgio hello, can you help me further? After registered, i wanted to show Logout button. But it didn't work. I have put `$_SESSION['login'] = true;` but it still didn't work. Where should I give you the full code?

Comment: @giorgio here is the full code. http://pastebin.com/VQ1NcY4k. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your extra bracket in your code block.

Remove the last brace (})

Comment: sorry, the question was not fully completed as I hide something. Can you check the question again? Thanks. Hope you can solve this! :)

Comment: cant find anything wrong. you will need to check your log files.